Why is my session database getting so big?
It feels like since the beginning of the year and Joomla 5 I have to empty my sessions database manually from time to time. It is now 1.9 GB in size. Why are the old entries not deleted automatically?
Here are my corresponding settings:

Are there any tips on how I can reduce the size without having to intervene manually?
Are there any other settings?
Many thanks for any advice!

You could change your Session Handler to use Filesystem, rather than Database, and PHP 'session management' will cull the older sessions and should keep your used space usage down.
Somewhere in the documentation for Joomla the recommendation is to use the Filesystem setting as it is more efficient however as to not all servers environments having PHP sessions available the default Joomla install is shipped with Database and it is intended you change it Filesystem if it is supported.
With either option, Database or Filesystem, you could set up a Cron job in you hosting account to issue the following command from your /cli directory;
php joomla.php session:gc

Depending on your Joomla installation and server environment set up it would look something like this in the Cron command field;
/usr/local/bin/php /home/youraccount/public_html/joomladir/cli/joomla.php session:gc


Admin Tools Pro also has a session cleaner option that can be configured to run every x minutes.

For all those who use Plesk. ‘Command’ (as above) does not work, but “Execute PHP script” does.
